# Compare String value to int value?

Tags: spring-boot

What to do if I want to compare String value to -1(int) value?
In my code "product.getCode()" returns string value and I have to check with -1 value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `String` to `int` value.

```
String code = product.getCode();
intn codeValue;
try {
  codeValue = Integer.parseInt(code);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  codeValue = 0;
}

System.out.println(codeValue);
System.out.println(codeValue == -1);
```

Comment: hi @derek .W .. need one more help

Answer (score 0):

Perform type conversion of String value to integer using `Integer.parseInt()` and then continue to compare like below:

```
int code = Integer.parseInt(product.getCode());
if(code == yourValue)
{
   //business logic
}
```